# For each row, find the next closest value in another table (Teradata)

Tags: teradata

I've seen a few close examples here but I'm not quite getting something close enough for me to noodle out a fix.

I have events, where trucks come in and out of a gate and I have two tables.  The first is all ingate events the second is all outgate events.  The problem is conceptually easy: For each ingate, find the nearest outgate.  The dilemma I have is that obviously trucks can come back.  So I might have 300 ingates for a unit on the ingate table with a corresponding 300 outgates.

Both tables look like this, except the other is session.Outgate

`session.Ingate`:

```
CHAS_INIT|  CHAS_NR   |     Ingate_TIME
---------+------------+---------------------
  MAEC   |   66862    | 2018-01-29-01.34.00
  MAEC   |   67218    | 2018-03-24-01.29.00
  MAEC   |   67557    | 2018-03-30-01.26.00
  MAEC   |   67557    | 2018-04-06-01.49.00
  MAEC   |   68773    | 2018-02-22-01.47.00
```

While this is a breeze to do in a spreadsheeting tool, I'm stumped on if it can be done during a join.  Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `my HTML skills were weak` - instead of worrying about aligning stuff in HTML or markup or whatever, please give us a fiddle as detailled  [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) (not rextester) - I don't know what the nearest mainstream server is to Teradata, but try PostgreSQL or Oracle on dbfiddle.uk - makes life easier for those of us who want to help you, avoids duplication of effort and gets you better and quicker answers!

Comment: I also don't know enough about Teradata to know if it's comparable to any of the SQL variants available on the various fiddle sites. If @Trives doesn't know, either, then taking a wild guess may not be the best possible idea; someone's valid PostgreSQL solution might have no chance of working in Teradata.

Comment: It may have to make a couple of assumptions: 1) a specific truck cannot leave before it entered the compound. 2) presumably, a specific truck would have to leave the compound before it could enter it again. Are these reasonable assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

```
select CHAS_INIT, CHAS_NR, Ingate_TIME,
   -- find the previous IN-time
   last_value(case when inout = 'i' then Ingate_TIME end ignore nulls)
   over (partition by CHAS_INIT, CHAS_NR -- does this determine a truck?
         order by Ingate_TIME)
from
 (  -- combine both in & out into a single result
    select 'i' as inout, CHAS_INIT, CHAS_NR, Ingate_TIME
    from session.Ingate
    union all 
    select 'o' as inout, CHAS_INIT, CHAS_NR, Ingate_TIME
    from session.Outgate
 ) as dt
-- only return OUT rows
qualify inout = 'o'
```